# R: regex first occurence based on condition

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to split strings by using the first white space coming after 3 characters. Here is my code:

```
string <- c("Le jour la nuit", "Les jours les nuits")
part1 <- sub("(\\S{3,})\\s?(.*)", "\\1", string)
part2 <- sub("(\\S{3,})\\s?(.*)", "\\2", string)

# output
> part1
[1] "Le jour" "Les"    
> part2
[1] "Le la nuit"      "jours les nuits"
```

For the first part, it works exactly as desired. However, it is not the case for the second part: `part2[1]` should be `la nuit` instead of `Le la nuit`.

I am not sure how achieve this and would be thankful for some guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you really want but per your requirements, you could use

```
^(.{3,}?)(?:(?<!,)\\s)+(.*)
```

This says:

```
^              # start of the string
(.{3,}?)       # capture 3+ characters lazily, up to...
(?:(?<!,)\\s)+ # 1+ whitespaces that must not be preceeded by a comma
(.*)           # capture the rest of the string
```

In `R`:

```
string <- c("Le jour la nuit", "Les jours les nuits", "les, jours les nuits")
(part1 <- sub("^(.{3,}?)(?:(?<!,)\\s)+(.*)", "\\1", string, perl = T))
(part2 <- sub("^(.{3,}?)(?:(?<!,)\\s)+(.*)", "\\2", string, perl = T))
```

Yielding

```
[1] "Le jour"    "Les"        "les, jours"
```

and

```
[1] "la nuit"         "jours les nuits" "les nuits"
```

---

Maybe you need a `dataframe` as a result, if so, you could define yourself a little function (using `sapply` and some logic):

```
make_df <- function(text) {
  parts <- sapply(text, function(x) {
    m <- regexec("^(.{3,}?)(?:(?<!,)\\s)+(.*)", x, perl = T)
    groups <- regmatches(x, m)
    c(groups[[1]][2], groups[[1]][3])
  }, USE.NAMES = F)
  (setNames(as.data.frame(t(parts), stringsAsFactors = F), c("part1", "part2")))
}

(df <- make_df(string))
```

This would yield for `string <- c("Le jour la nuit", "Les jours les nuits", "les, jours les nuits", "somejunk")`:

```
       part1           part2
1    Le jour         la nuit
2        Les jours les nuits
3 les, jours       les nuits
4       <NA>            <NA>
```

Comment: That solves it, thanks. My aim is to use the first white space coming after 3 characters (letters including `ä,ü,...` or punctuation) to split my strings.

Comment: do you know how to modify the pattern s.t. `"les, jours les nuits"` gets `c("les, jours", "les nuits")`, i.e. ignoring white spaces coming after commas?

Comment: @A.Grothendieck: Have updated the answer, you could use a lookbehind with `perl = TRUE` making sure that a whitespace is not preceeded by a comma.